# Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred status Code 12152

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, windows-server-2003

I have created a website and host it on windows server 2003. I have used Ajax 3.5 with update panel tag in whole page.

My first page is home page which contails only a dropdown and a button.

when I select the text from dropdown and click on button. It redirects the main page.

Main page contains some textboxes and on button in update panel.

For eg.

```
<CC1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server"  />
            <div>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="update" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="960px">
            <tr> 
            <td align="left">
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlAjax" runat="server" Width="500px" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="5" BorderColor="Brown">
        // Code Here
        // This a the few part of the code.
           </asp:panel>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <asp:button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" text="Submit"/>
        </td>
        </tr>

        </table>
         </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I didn't use Asyncpostbacktrigger tag. when I filled the details in textboxes and click on submit button to save the details in sql server database. It don't processes and redirect to home page which contains dropdown and a button Without showing any message on windows server 2003. When I run this website from IIS it showing the below message:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 12152
```

I have googled about this in but no helps. What is the issue? And interesting thing is this website is working fine on Windows XP. Please help to resolve the issue.

Comment: are you using Response.Redirect() is serverside code

Answer (score 0):

When using AJAX, any client-side scripts coming from the server should use the ScriptManager class.  In this case, because you want it to run immediately, use `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript().`

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "MyScript", "confirm('Select True or False in exempt field.')", true);
```

Comment: I have already use the line in my code. Why this page redirect to home page without any error message when click on button?

Comment: @DineshKumar:see here http://vijaymodi.wordpress.com/2007/04/13/syswebformspagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception/